# cakephp join more than 2 tables at once in one join table

Tags: cakephp, join

I have converted many of my projects across to Cake with success, but I have one that poses a challenge that I am struggling with.

In a typical "`hasMany through`" join, eg. in the Cake docs, you have 3 tables, `Student`, `Course` and `CourseMembership`. `Student` and `Course hasMany CourseMembership` and `CourseMembership belongsTo Student` and `Course`.

My question is, is it possible, using normal convention, to join more than two tables together in this way? For example, adding another table, say, `Lecturer` (forget the real world possibilities of this) would create more possible permutations but can Cake handle this natively?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here would be the table layout for the join (HTH):

```
id | student_id | course_id | lecturer_id
```

EDIT 2: by default, the join table would be called `course_students` so what I am after is a table called `course_lecturer_students` with the above layout (obviously it doesn't need to be called that but just to comply with CakePHP naming convention).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Cakephp for

1. Write simple sql as query ( no recomendable )
2. Write join sentences
3. use deep associations ( recomendable )

However you question is not clear and is not possible to determinate which kind of answer you are looking for, or what are you looking for

Probably you could extends with a final result of what you are looking for in order to help you

Comment: Number 3). I want 3, 4 or even 5 tables joined through 1 join table. I know I can do it, what I want to know is the convention (if any) for doing it.

Comment: I usually use deep relations ship, for exmaple

$this->MyModel->bindModel(array(
'belongsTo' => array(
'OneModel' => array(
'className'=>'OtherModel',
'foreignKey' = FALSE,
'conditions' => 'OneModel.id = OtherModel.one_model_id'
),
........ // Deeping as needed
)
));

This way, also work on HasOne, depending on wich kind of relation do you have staring on your model base
This is teh better way, join sentense usually work well with mysql, but no well with other da like postgres or sqlite, binding models could be better

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely.  You can `Join` as many tables as you'd like really.  Using CakePHP to Join is no different than using MySQL to run a Join query - CakePHP just takes the CakePHP syntax and creates the MySQL (or whatever) query for you.

Side note - Just make sure you're indexing your tables correctly.