# CakePHP: How to use Containable for nested HABTM models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to use Containable to return a model with several of its associated models (and those arrays of data). The models deal with test results. Here are the models:

Models:

```
Question : has and belongs to many Category
Category : has and belongs to many Question
Attempt : has many AttemptedQuestions
AttemptedQuestion : belongs to Question
```

I want to return an Attempt with all of it's AttemptedQuestions and *their* corresponding Quesions + Category

So basically, the relationships map like this:

`Attempt => AttemptedQuestion(s) => Question => Category`

I suspect that because of the HABTM relationship, Cake would prefer to return:

`Attempt => AttemptedQuestion(s) => array( Question, Category )` <--Categories are not contained within the Question array, but rather they are sisters. This is fine as well.

At the moment I am unable to get Category to show up at all. Here's what I'm doing inside a controller (this does NOT result in the Categories appearing in results):

```
$this->Attempt->contain(array('AttemptedQuestion' => array('Question'=>'Category'))); 
$attempt_to_be_graded = $this->Attempt->findById( $attempt_id );
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
Here's a revision based on the answer from @nunser. This also does not work.

```
$this->Attempt->contain(array('AttemptedQuestion' => array('Question'=>array('Question'=>array('Category') )))); 
$attempt_to_be_graded = $this->Attempt->findById($attempt_id );
```

This is what the data returned looks like:

```
array(
    'Attempt' => array(
        'id' => '39',
        ...
    ),
    'AttemptedQuestion' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '189',
            ...,
            'Question' => array(
                'id' => '165',
                ...
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '188',
            ...,
            'Question' => array(
                'id' => '164',
                ...
            )
        )

    )
)
```

**Update 2**

I'm still struggling with this, but I think my associations have to be correct because the following returns a list of all my Categories just as expected:

`$categories = $this->Attempt->AttemptedQuestion->Question->Category->find('all');`

**Update 3**

I've narrowed down the scope of this problem by testing the results of `$this->Question->find('first')` from various points throughout the code. It appears that the results are expected UNTIL after this: `$test = $this->Test->findById($test_id);`.

Here is the code which demonstrates:

```
    $this->loadModel('Question');       
    $test = $this->Question->find('first');
    debug($test);
//THESE RESULTS INCLUDE Category DATE

    $test = $this->Test->findById($test_id);

    $this->loadModel('Question');       
    $test = $this->Question->find('first');
    debug($test);
    exit;
//THESE RESULTS DO NOT INCLUDE Category DATE
```

So for reasons I completely do not understand, the intervening `Test->find()` seems to prevent the Category data from appearing afterwards. Weird, huh?

Comment: What data source are you using? MySQL or MSSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, on my side is better to use binModel nested instead of a behavior, cause is more configurable, check please this link, and you probably could help you on your question

[CakePHP - Building a Complex Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241683/cakephp-building-a-complex-query/14845771#14845771)

[cakephp join more than 2 tables at once in one join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209014/cakephp-join-more-than-2-tables-at-once-in-one-join-table/16218491#16218491)

Answer (score 1):

### HABTM Headaches

These are difficult to manage in Cake. What I've started doing is called "hasMany Threw" which is [described in the book here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model).

The advantage is more control over find queries. It requires an additional `Model` be added, but it's worth it. The automated handling of HABTM in CakePHP is often difficult to understand. Using associations to explicitly define the relationships is more flexible.

### Circular Reference

Your Models are currently setup with a circular reference, and this can be problematic for a HABTM.

```
Question : has and belongs to many Category
Category : has and belongs to many Question
```

It is very difficult in Cake to create a HABTM on both models. Usually this is done only on one of them, and I'd pick `Question`. With a "hasMany Threw" it's easier.

### HasMany Threw

If we use a "hasMany Threw" then the containable rules become a lot easier to explain.

```
Question : hasMany QuestionCategory
Category : hasMany QuestionCategory
QuestionCategory : belongs to Question, belongs to Category.
Attempt : belongs to Question
```

Now, I removed `AttamptedQuestion`. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to model, but if a person can create multiple Attempts per Question, then it's not needed. Just create more then one Attempt record.

### Find All Records For An Attempt

To find all the associated records for an `Attempt` using `Containable` the find would be as follows.

```
$this->Attempt->find('first',array(
    'conditions'=>array('Attempt.id'=>$attempt_id),
    'contain'=>array(
        'Question'=>array(
            'QuestionCategory'=>array(
                'Category'=>array()
            )
        )
    ));
```

You can still add back the `AttemptedQuestion` model, and just contain it before `Question`.

### Ambiguous Fieldnames With Associations

You should get into the habit of using `Attempt.id` in conditions instead of just `id`. When you uses associations there are often duplicate fieldnames in the SQL result. You need to clarify which ones you are referring to, because you can also have `Question.id` as a condition in `Attempt` if a `JOIN` is used. So `id` is ambiguous on it's own.

Comment: This is so great!! Thanks! To clarify: AttemptedQuestions are records of the individual "answers" that comprise an Attempt. So an Attempt hasMany AttemptedQuestions. This is how we reconstruct a user's Attempt. I don't think this changes anything about what you said, but I wanted to clarify just in case.

Comment: Darn! It still doesn't work. I changed all the model associations as you described and I still get the same data (no category). The most frustrating part is that there are no errors. Just missing the data I want. Ugh.

Comment: Does it find any `QuestionCategory` records?

Comment: I tested this in the exact same controller action and it worked: `  $this->loadModel('QuestionCategory');
   $qc = $this->QuestionCategory->find('all');
   debug($qc);
`

Comment: @Emerson put `Containable` into your `AppModel`.

Comment: It turns out that all the models already had Containable... But here's some big news: when I add the above test, the following `$this->Attempt->find...` DOES include the 'QuestionCategory' data. When I remove it, it DOESN'T. I have not idea why that preceding find() should effect the output of the following, but at least that's some progress. Any guess what's going on here?

Comment: @Emerson oh that tells me Cake can't find one of your models so it's creating a default model. Which doesn't have any of the associations set for it. Check that you've named all your files/classes correctly.

Comment: Interesting... specifically looking for mismatches between the expected file name and the class names?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31286/discussion-between-mathew-foscarini-and-emerson)

Comment: I may have a new clue why my associations aren't working as expected! I just noticed that one of my controller files was missing the "s" expected by Cake's naming conventions. BlaBlaBlaController instead of BlaBlaBlasController. I get the feeling CakPHP has some tolerance for this, since the app is basically working. But I'm really curious to hear if you think this might have some connection to the associations puzzle.

Comment: @Emerson sorry, I don't think that's it. I've used singular names for controller before without problems. Singular model names are need to generate the name of the table, but controllers are less restrictive.

Comment: @Emerson can you send me the database schema for these tables, i'll quickly see if I can reproduce it here. Also, what version of cake are you using.

Comment: I'm on v2.3.0 and I'll email you the schema momentarily.

Comment: Just emailed you the schema and the models. Also, I have another (potentially) interesting clue: `$this->Question->find('first');` DOES include the Category data when I call it from inside QuestionsController. So the problem is somehow isolated to when I try it in a DIFFERENT controller (even after `loadModel('Question')`)

Comment: Hey again. I just added a 3rd update to the question above with what I think is another important clue.

Answer (score 1):

Give the new information about what triggers the problem.

```
$this->loadModel('Question');       
$test = $this->Question->find('first');
debug($test);
//THESE RESULTS INCLUDE Category DATE

$test = $this->Test->findById($test_id);

$this->loadModel('Question');       
$test = $this->Question->find('first');
debug($test);
exit;
//THESE RESULTS DO NOT INCLUDE Category DATE
```

In the above scenario the `findById` magic function (that's what I call them) calls the lower level data source driver to perform the query.

In the `DboSource.php` it's not using the `Containable` behavior to control recursion, and changes the `recursive` property in the `Model`. I think this is causing the trouble with the `Containable` behavior.

You can fix this by reset the `recursive` back to it's default after the `findById`.

```
$test = $this->Test->findById($test_id);
$this->Test->recursive = 1;

$this->loadModel('Question');       
$test = $this->Question->find('first');
debug($test);
exit;
```

I'm going to guess this fixes the problem, but you have to remember to reset it after using `findById` or any other magic function.

This should be report to the Cake developers as a bug if it's reproducible.

**EDIT:**

recursive default is 1 not 0.

Comment: We're definitely getting somewhere, but it still doesn't work. I tried resetting recursive afterwards. I also tried replacing the magic `findById()` with the normal `find('first', array('conditions'=>id...)` and neither caused the second debug() to display the Category data. Hmmm.

Comment: It may also be relevant that there is a `$this->Test->contain(...)` ABOVE the testing code. When I comment THAT out, the intervening Test->find... no longer strips the Category data out of Question->find... So it seems to be a combination of that Test->find + Containable that mysteriously affects the results from the Question->find...

Comment: @Emerson this is crazy. All my code uses regular `find(..)` with the `contain` inside the find options. I don't use the `contain(..)` method or magic methods. Try doing it that way.

Comment: I've been experimenting with that (normal find())... but I think I may have figured it out!! It looks like the `contain()` condition placed on the Test->find is affecting the `Question->find`s as well. I added additional deeper associations into the Test->contain to include ...Question=>Category... and it *seems* to be working as expected now. I need to test more, but I think I'm on to something.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->Attempt->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$attempt_id),
                                'contain'=>array('AttemptedQuestion'=> 
                                               array('Question' => 
                                                  array('Category')
                                               )
                                )));
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use find('first') instead of findById()?

Comment: I updated the question with what I think is yours suggestion. It's still not working. I also tried using your exact code (find('first'...) and the results also did not include the Category.

Comment: I just use it because I prefer to have my `contain` logic inside each query instead of the general `$this->Model->contain` one. I saw your update, but did you also tried it with the full `find('first')`?

Comment: Yes. I tried copy/pasting your exact code and it returned the same thing (no Category key in the data array).

Comment: I added the data array that's returned with your (and my) version, in case that's useful.

Comment: Is this a situation where I might need to string multiple models before the `find()`? Something like: `$this->Attempt->AttemptedQuestion->...`? I remember having to do this in the past but I'm a little fuzzy on exactly how that syntax works, so I'm not sure if it's relevant here.