# CakePHP: Model->Model->find()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

This is a really basic question but it's not explained in [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html).

What exactly happens when you sting together multiple models before the find method?

Ex: `$stuff = $this->Article->User->find('all');`

How is this different than: `$this->User->Article->find('all');`

Can you do more than two? `$this->Book->Chapter->Author->find('all');`

It's clear that it has something to do with the relationships between the models, but I thought those were defined in the models, so I'm not clear what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set an association on a Model. CakePHP instantiates it at runtime and sets it as an Object property for that model.

```
class User extends AppModel
{
      public $hasMany = array('Document');
}

class Document extends AppModel
{
}
```

In the above example. `User` objects will contain a property called `Document`, but `Document` will not contain `User`.

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
     public $uses = array('User');

     public function index()
     {
           $this->User-find(...); // works
           $this->User->Document->find(..); // works, because of the hasMany

           $document = ClassRegistry::init('Document');
           $document->User->find(...); // does not work, not associated to User.
     }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that the name of the property is the alias for the association. Not the name of the model.

```
class User extends AppModel
{
      public $hasMany = array(
           'Paper'=>array('className'=>'Document')
      );
}

class Document extends AppModel
{
}
```

This changes the property name to `Paper`

```
$this->User->Paper->find(..); // works as alias
```

Uses aliases on associations allows you to apply find conditions so that they generate different results.

```
class User extends AppModel
{
      public $hasMany = array(
           'Paper'=>array('className'=>'Document','conditions'=>array(....)),
           'Resume'=>array('className'=>'Document','conditions'=>array(....))
      );
}
```

That would create two properties for `User` models like so.

```
$this->User->Paper->find(..); // works as alias
$this->User->Resume->find(..); // works as alias
```

But, the conditions only apply when performing a find on the `User` model.

Comment: This is helpful, and explains when it can be used. But I'm still not clear on WHAT it's actually doing. In other words, how, if at all, is the returned data effected?

Comment: Maybe it's more clear if I ask specifically: Which model is being searched? The last in the chain? Or are both being searched? Would `$this->User->Paper->find('all')` return all the documents? Or documents AND users?

Comment: `$this->User->Document == $this->Document` is true. The two objects are the same instance of the `Document` model. Cake sets `Document` as a member property to `User` for convenient access. In your controller you don't have to say `uses = array('User','Document')`. Since `User` already has a reference to `Document`. You also don't have to call `ClassRegistry::init('Document')` from inside `User` model.

Comment: @Emerson `$this->User->Document->find(...)` searches the `Document` model. It does not matter that it's an object property of `User` or any other model. `Document` model is the SAME instance no matter where you get it from. All models in CakePHP are singletons.

Comment: @Emerson `$this->Model->Model->Model->find(..)` is not a notation that has any impact on the `find` query. The `find` statement applies only to the object that method is called on. Which would be the one left of the `->` member access operator.

Comment: Perfect. This clears it up. So if I'm understanding correctly, find options like `contain` don't care whether the context is `$this->Document->find()` or `$this->Model->Document->find()`. I ask this because I'm totally stuck on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944836/cakephp-how-to-use-containable-for-nested-habtm-models