# CakePHP: Is there a limit to the depth of associations when using find()?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am struggling to get this to work:

```
$this->Attempt->contain(array('AttemptedQuestion' => array('Question'=>array('Category') ))); //THIS DOESNT WORK
$attempt_to_be_graded = $this->Attempt->findById( $attempt_id );
```

The resulting data is structured as follows ( *no* Category ):

```
array(
    Attempt => array(),
    AttemptedQuestion => array(
        0 => array(
            Question => array()
        ),
        1 => array(
            Question => array()
        ), 
        2 => array(
            Question => array()
        )
    )
)
```

I think my model associations must be correct because this works fine:

`$categories = $this->Attempt->AttemptedQuestion->Question->Category->find('all');`

Why is there no Category data in the data returned above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP: How to use Containable for nested HABTM models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944836/cakephp-how-to-use-containable-for-nested-habtm-models)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no limit at all. But if there is a limit, it's definitely not 3 levels deep! Make sure your associations are defined both ways (ie, Category BelongsTo Question, as well as Question HasMany Category.

Comment: Containable can take lots of associations. The most I've used is 9.

Comment: That pretty much answers my question. If one of you submits an answer I will accept it. Although a definitive number of the limit (if there is one) would probably help a lot of other folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is no limit. I cannot prove this, but the problem I was encountering is not caused by hitting a limit and I've seen examples of much deeper associations working correctly.